# How do i derive an expression for the worst case number of comparisons needed to merge two sorted arrays of length n/2

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

merge sort uses divide and conquer approach

Comment: So what have you done to answer this question yourself? Any research done? Any attempt?

Comment: Do you mean the worst case for the usual implementation or do you mean the theoretical lower bound ?

Answer (score 0):

The worst case number of comparisons needed to merge two sorted arrays of length /2 is −1.

This is because when two values have been compared with each other, one of those two values will never be used in a comparison again: it is the value that follows the sorted order... and it is no longer part of the rest of the merge process.

In the worst case, the last comparison will be between the last value of the first array and the last value of the second array. All the other (−2) values were already excluded from further comparisons, so that means we already did −2 comparisons. Now the last one executes, which completes the comparison count to be −1.

#### Example of a worst case input

```
 = 10
A = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
B = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comparisons during the merge:

```
0  1
2  1
2  3
4  3
4  5
6  5
6  7
8  7
8  9
```

#### Example of a best case input

Just to put this in perspective, the best case occurs when the last value of the first array is less than the first value of the second array (or vice versa). This only needs  / 2 comparisons.

```
 = 10
A = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comparisons during the merge:

```
0 5
1 5
2 5
3 5
4 5
```

No more comparisons are now needed, because the first list has no more values; only the values of the second list remain: but they don't need to be compared with anything, and can be appended to the result in the order they currently occur.

#### Remark

The fact that this process is used as part of merge sort -- implementing a divide and conquer algorithm -- is just background info. Merging two sorted lists can be needed in other contexts that do not relate to merge sort.